# Como chamar um método de um controller através de JS ou Ajax no laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, método, controller

sou novo com PHP e Laravel, além disso não entendo muito de JS.

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, eu tenho uma view que exibe as informações do prestador de serviço do meu projeto, antes que esse cara esteja apto a trabalhar preciso validar o cadastro dele, sendo assim eu válido as informações, se estiverem corretas quero clicar em um botão Aprovar que via JS ou AJAX vai chamar um método do controller do prestador e vai alterar o status dele dentro do sistema, porém não sei como fazer isso, alguém possui algum exemplo para que eu possa me basear?

View:

```
@extends('templates.template-admin')
@section('content')
    <h1 class="text-center">Informações do prestadores</h1>
    <div class="col-8 m-auto">
        @csrf

        {{-- Fazendo select para encontrar o endereço e a cidade usando o relacionamento feito entre as tabelas --}}
        @php
            $endereco = $prestadores->find($prestadores->ID)
                                    ->relEndereco;  

            $cidade = $enderecos->find($enderecos->ID)
                                ->relCidade;     
                               
            $certificado = $prestadores->find($prestadores->ID)
                                    ->relCertificado;  

        @endphp

        Nome:{{$prestadores->NOME}}<br>
        CPF:{{$prestadores->CPF}}<br>
        Telefone:{{$prestadores->TELEFONE}}<br>
        Data de Nascimento:{{$prestadores->DT_NASCIMENTO}}<br>
        E-mail:{{$prestadores->EMAIL}}<br>
        CEP:{{$endereco->CEP}}<br>
        Endereço:{{$endereco->ENDERECO}}<br>
        Número:{{$endereco->NUMERO}}<br>
        Bairro:{{$endereco->BAIRRO}}<br>
        Cidade:{{$cidade->CIDADE}}<br>
        Estado:{{$cidade->UF}}<br>
        @if ($certificados->CERTIFICADO)
            Certificado:<a href="{{url("storage/{$certificados->CERTIFICADO}")}}" target="_blank">
                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-earmark-medical" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M4 1h5v1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V6h1v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
                    <path d="M9 4.5V1l5 5h-3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 4.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.634l.549-.317a.5.5 0 1 1 .5.866L8 6l.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5.866L7.5 6.866V7.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-.634l-.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5-.866L6 6l-.549-.317a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.866l.549.317V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 7 4zM5 9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        @endif
        <br>
        @if ($antecedentes->ANTECEDENTE)
            Antedecentes:<a href="{{url("storage/{$antecedentes->ANTECEDENTE}")}}" target="_blank">
                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-earmark-medical" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M4 1h5v1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V6h1v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
                    <path d="M9 4.5V1l5 5h-3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 4.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.634l.549-.317a.5.5 0 1 1 .5.866L8 6l.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5.866L7.5 6.866V7.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-.634l-.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5-.866L6 6l-.549-.317a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.866l.549.317V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 7 4zM5 9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        @endif
        <br><br>
        <a href="">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Aprovar</button>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Reprovar</button>
        </a>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Método do controller que quero chamar:

```
public function aprovar($id)
    {
        
        // Pegando o valor da constant para colocar no prestador
        // $statusAprovado = \Config::get('constants.STATUS.ATIVO');
        // $status = App\Models\prestadores::find($id);
        // $status->STATUS = $statusAprovado;
        // $status->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu projeto ou no arquivo blade você pode chamar um arquivo ou pode ser dentro mesmo do código um trecho JavaScript.

Mas antes de chamar você pode importar um arquivo ou usar um CDN de um [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) para ficar mais fácil:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/suarota/1',
      type: 'put',
      dataType: 'json'      
   }).then( response =>{
       //o retorno do processamento
   })
</script>
```

na rota você prepara para receber o código enviado pelo ajax

```
Route::put('/suarota/{id}', 'HomeController@aprovar');
```

Não esqueça de alterar a rota e o código que você precisa alterar

Espero que tenha dado uma luz

Comment: Me ajudou muito, obrigado :)